# cumulative sum till target reached in mysql

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

I have following tables,

Workout Data:

```
Date       User        Distance     Calories        
1614944833   1           100            32
1614944232   2           100            43
1624944831   1           150            23
1615944832   3           250            63
1614644836   1           500            234 
1614954835   2           100            55
1614344834   3           100            34
1614964831   1           260            23
1614944238   1           200            44
```

user_subdomain Data:

```
    User        sub_domain
    1           3
    2           3           
    3           3
    4           2
```

Subdomain data:

```
    subdomain       name
    3               test1 
    4               test2
```

I would like to get sum value of distance,calories,count of records once they user reached sum of distance >= 1000.we should not count remaining records if user crossed 1000 distance.( if user crossed 1000,then 1000 else max distance value).

Expected Output:

```
Date       record_count Distance    Calories    
1614964831   4          1000        312
1614954835   2          200         98
1614344834   3          350         97
```

So This result shows each users total effort they used to reach distance 1000 by record_count,then if they reached 1000 above then calculated as 1000,else max reached distance value,then total sum of that calories till 1000 cumulative sum reached.This is the output i need to retrieve.I tried with below query,but not works

Can anyone suggest with cumulative sum inner join method or any other solution for this?

Comment: I think you want to look into GROUP BY, along with SUM

Comment: yes,but not able to skip remaining records if user reached 1000.that is isue

Comment: Distance over 1000 can be handled by display logic, or maybe MAX. Do you want to ignore calories after a distance of 1000?

Comment: yes,above workout table have 5 records for userid 1.that user crossed 1000 by first 4 records,so need to sum calories for first 4 records and distance as 1000,then record_count as 4.like that i need to retrieve,last 5th record will be skipped in this calculation

Comment: please clarify the order to read records, the expected result does not order by any of the columns.

Comment: i need to order the result by user asc,date asc

Comment: Check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12113699/231316

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use `window functions` in next way:

```
with cumulative as (
  -- calculate cumulative Distance & Calories
  select 
      User,
      Distance,
      Calories,
      sum(Distance) over (partition by User order by Date) SumDistance,
      sum(Calories) over (partition by User order by Date) SumCalories
  from Workout
  order by User, Date
) select 
    User, max(SumDistance), max(SumCalories)
from cumulative
where SumDistance - Distance < 1000 -- filter
group by User;
```

[MySQL window functions](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/87612a610ac701edec7ceb671517d309/)

Comment: that gets really close, but I think they also want to throw away calories when the distance has been reached. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=236cb115bcd1279d83cb26ed88a735a3

Comment: this query not works in phpmyadmin and shows syntax error

Comment: What MySQL version you have?